# mod_rewrite P flag sets X-Forwarded-For?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-headers

Does the `P`roxy flag in mod_rewrite set the X-Forwarded-For header? If not, is there any way to set this header prior to doing the redirect?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no practical experience with it, but according to [Wikipedia's article on X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For#Proxy_servers_and_caching_engines), Apache's `mod_proxy` (which handles the `P` flag) does set the header.

The [mod_proxy docs themselves](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) seem silent on the issue.

Comment: If in doubt, look at the source code: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/proxy/mod_proxy_http.c?view=markup